# assembly quiz - phase6

Tags: assembly, gdb, reverse-engineering

I've been solving the quiz about assembly codes but the Quiz6(phase 6) is really hard for me to figure out what is it doing.
I just catch that the input of phase 6 is **six integers**, each integer is identical, and under equal 6.
I wrote some other details inside of the code lines below.

What Phase_6 says:

```
Dump of assembler code for function phase_6:
=> 0x00005555555554fd <+0>: push   %r14
   0x00005555555554ff <+2>: push   %r13
   0x0000555555555501 <+4>: push   %r12
   0x0000555555555503 <+6>: push   %rbp
   0x0000555555555504 <+7>: push   %rbx
   0x0000555555555505 <+8>: sub    $0x60,%rsp
   0x0000555555555509 <+12>:    mov    %fs:0x28,%rax
   0x0000555555555512 <+21>:    mov    %rax,0x58(%rsp)
   0x0000555555555517 <+26>:    xor    %eax,%eax
   0x0000555555555519 <+28>:    mov    %rsp,%r13
   0x000055555555551c <+31>:    mov    %r13,%rsi
   0x000055555555551f <+34>:    callq  0x555555555aba <read_six_numbers>
   0x0000555555555524 <+39>:    mov    %r13,%r12
   0x0000555555555527 <+42>:    mov    $0x0,%r14d
   0x000055555555552d <+48>:    jmp    0x555555555554 <phase_6+87>
   0x000055555555552f <+50>:    callq  0x555555555a7e <explode_bomb>
   0x0000555555555534 <+55>:    jmp    0x555555555563 <phase_6+102>
   0x0000555555555536 <+57>:    add    $0x1,%ebx
   0x0000555555555539 <+60>:    cmp    $0x5,%ebx
   0x000055555555553c <+63>:    jg     0x555555555550 <phase_6+83>
   0x000055555555553e <+65>:    movslq %ebx,%rax
   0x0000555555555541 <+68>:    mov    (%rsp,%rax,4),%eax
   0x0000555555555544 <+71>:    cmp    %eax,0x0(%rbp)
   0x0000555555555547 <+74>:    jne    0x555555555536 <phase_6+57>
   0x0000555555555549 <+76>:    callq  0x555555555a7e <explode_bomb>
   // Upper cods seems to test the identicality and integers are under equal 6


   //And I have no idea what are below codelines do. From here...
   0x000055555555554e <+81>:    jmp    0x555555555536 <phase_6+57>
   0x0000555555555550 <+83>:    add    $0x4,%r13
   0x0000555555555554 <+87>:    mov    %r13,%rbp
   0x0000555555555557 <+90>:    mov    0x0(%r13),%eax
   0x000055555555555b <+94>:    sub    $0x1,%eax
   0x000055555555555e <+97>:    cmp    $0x5,%eax
   0x0000555555555561 <+100>:   ja     0x55555555552f <phase_6+50>
   0x0000555555555563 <+102>:   add    $0x1,%r14d
   0x0000555555555567 <+106>:   cmp    $0x6,%r14d
   0x000055555555556b <+110>:   je     0x555555555572 <phase_6+117>
   0x000055555555556d <+112>:   mov    %r14d,%ebx
   0x0000555555555570 <+115>:   jmp    0x55555555553e <phase_6+65>
   0x0000555555555572 <+117>:   lea    0x18(%r12),%rcx
   0x0000555555555577 <+122>:   mov    $0x7,%edx
   0x000055555555557c <+127>:   mov    %edx,%eax
   0x000055555555557e <+129>:   sub    (%r12),%eax
   0x0000555555555582 <+133>:   mov    %eax,(%r12)
   0x0000555555555586 <+137>:   add    $0x4,%r12
   0x000055555555558a <+141>:   cmp    %r12,%rcx
   0x000055555555558d <+144>:   jne    0x55555555557c <phase_6+127>
   0x000055555555558f <+146>:   mov    $0x0,%esi
   0x0000555555555594 <+151>:   jmp    0x5555555555b0 <phase_6+179>
   0x0000555555555596 <+153>:   mov    0x8(%rdx),%rdx
   0x000055555555559a <+157>:   add    $0x1,%eax
   0x000055555555559d <+160>:   cmp    %ecx,%eax
   0x000055555555559f <+162>:   jne    0x555555555596 <phase_6+153>
   0x00005555555555a1 <+164>:   mov    %rdx,0x20(%rsp,%rsi,8)
   0x00005555555555a6 <+169>:   add    $0x1,%rsi
   0x00005555555555aa <+173>:   cmp    $0x6,%rsi
   0x00005555555555ae <+177>:   je     0x5555555555c6 <phase_6+201>
   0x00005555555555b0 <+179>:   mov    (%rsp,%rsi,4),%ecx
   0x00005555555555b3 <+182>:   mov    $0x1,%eax
   0x00005555555555b8 <+187>:   lea    0x202c71(%rip),%rdx        # 0x555555758230 <node1>
   0x00005555555555bf <+194>:   cmp    $0x1,%ecx
   0x00005555555555c2 <+197>:   jg     0x555555555596 <phase_6+153>
   0x00005555555555c4 <+199>:   jmp    0x5555555555a1 <phase_6+164>
   0x00005555555555c6 <+201>:   mov    0x20(%rsp),%rbx
   0x00005555555555cb <+206>:   mov    0x28(%rsp),%rax
   0x00005555555555d0 <+211>:   mov    %rax,0x8(%rbx)
   0x00005555555555d4 <+215>:   mov    0x30(%rsp),%rdx
   0x00005555555555d9 <+220>:   mov    %rdx,0x8(%rax)
   0x00005555555555dd <+224>:   mov    0x38(%rsp),%rax
   0x00005555555555e2 <+229>:   mov    %rax,0x8(%rdx)
   0x00005555555555e6 <+233>:   mov    0x40(%rsp),%rdx
   0x00005555555555eb <+238>:   mov    %rdx,0x8(%rax)
   0x00005555555555ef <+242>:   mov    0x48(%rsp),%rax
   0x00005555555555f4 <+247>:   mov    %rax,0x8(%rdx)
   0x00005555555555f8 <+251>:   movq   $0x0,0x8(%rax)
   0x0000555555555600 <+259>:   mov    $0x5,%ebp
   0x0000555555555605 <+264>:   jmp    0x555555555610 <phase_6+275>
   // ...To Here


   //I think this block is compareing $rbx, *($rbx + 8), .... with ($rbx)
   //but gdb says can't read the memory *($rbx + 8), *(*($rbx + 8) + 8), ...things.
   //Only it reads $rbx
   0x0000555555555607 <+266>:   mov    0x8(%rbx),%rbx
   0x000055555555560b <+270>:   sub    $0x1,%ebp
   0x000055555555560e <+273>:   je     0x555555555621 <phase_6+292>
   0x0000555555555610 <+275>:   mov    0x8(%rbx),%rax
   0x0000555555555614 <+279>:   mov    (%rax),%eax
   0x0000555555555616 <+281>:   cmp    %eax,(%rbx)
   0x0000555555555618 <+283>:   jge    0x555555555607 <phase_6+266>
   0x000055555555561a <+285>:   callq  0x555555555a7e <explode_bomb>
   0x000055555555561f <+290>:   jmp    0x555555555607 <phase_6+266>



   0x0000555555555621 <+292>:   mov    0x58(%rsp),%rax
   0x0000555555555626 <+297>:   xor    %fs:0x28,%rax
   0x000055555555562f <+306>:   jne    0x55555555563e <phase_6+321>
   0x0000555555555631 <+308>:   add    $0x60,%rsp
   0x0000555555555635 <+312>:   pop    %rbx
   0x0000555555555636 <+313>:   pop    %rbp
   0x0000555555555637 <+314>:   pop    %r12
   0x0000555555555639 <+316>:   pop    %r13
   0x000055555555563b <+318>:   pop    %r14
   0x000055555555563d <+320>:   retq   
   0x000055555555563e <+321>:   callq  0x555555554e90 <__stack_chk_fail@plt>
End of assembler dump.
```

I also tried `until *0x0000555555555618` and `ni` for recognize the process flow, but... no idea what is the rule...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found it.

This phase has linked-list nodes whose size is 16 bytes.  (Note the `mov    0x8(%rbx),%rbx` pointer-chasing `p = p->next` qword load from an offset of +8 relative the start of the node.

We can ignore the high dword of the pointers because they're all the same (x86 being little-endian), and just look at the first 3  dwords of each node with a GDB `eXamine` format of `/3x`, using the default size of 32-bit elements.

```
Breakpoint 1, 0x00005555555554fd in phase_6 ()
(gdb) until *0x0000555555555618
0x0000555555555618 in phase_6 ()
(gdb) x/3x $rdx-16
0x555555758230 <node1>: 0x00000189  0x00000001  0x00000000
(gdb) x/3x $rdx
0x555555758240 <node2>: 0x00000113  0x00000002  0x55758230
(gdb) x/3x $rdx+16
0x555555758250 <node3>: 0x0000007f  0x00000003  0x55758240
(gdb) x/3x $rdx+32
0x555555758260 <node4>: 0x000000ff  0x00000004  0x55758250
(gdb) x/3x $rdx+48
0x555555758270 <node5>: 0x000001fd  0x00000005  0x55758260
(gdb) x/3x $rbx
0x555555758110 <node6>: 0x000003b3  0x00000006  0x55758270
```

and when I gave `1 2 3 4 5 6` as input the program checks the validity in order of `6 5 4 3 2 1`.
If the input is `1 5 3 4 2 6`, it checks `6 2 4 3 5 1`.

**input = a, b, c, d, e** -> **check = 7-a, 7-b, 7-c, 7-d, 7-e**

The validity is checked by

```
   0x0000555555555616 <+281>:   cmp    %eax,(%rbx)
   0x0000555555555618 <+283>:   jge    0x555555555607 <phase_6+266>
```

if the value of `node 7-a` is bigger than `node 7-b`, the program says OK. if not NO.

And the **value** of each node is...

```
0x555555758230 <node1>: 0x00000189
0x555555758240 <node2>: 0x00000113
0x555555758250 <node3>: 0x0000007f
0x555555758260 <node4>: 0x000000ff
0x555555758270 <node5>: 0x000001fd
0x555555758110 <node6>: 0x000003b3
```

so the answer is `1 2 6 5 3 4` !!

Comment: `x` isn't a size, it's a format (hex).  GDB is using the default element size of 4 bytes.

Comment: In x86 terminology, 3 DWORDs.  (In x86, a "word" is always 2 bytes, instead of redefining it depending on the mode the CPU is executing in.  That's why q = quadword means 8 bytes, as in `movq` or `cmpq`.)  But in GDB terminology, 3 `w`ords (`x /3wx`).  GDB is not x86-centric, and doesn't change depending on whether you're debugging x86 or MIPS or whatever.  So probably the best thing to say is 3 dwords, because that's unambiguous in an x86 Q&A.

Comment: I was going to edit that into your answer since you forgot to, but then I realized that your answer needed fixing.  As you found, nodes are 16 bytes apart, but all 16 bytes are used, not just 12.

Comment: oh right i forgot it.... i’m not english user so my answer has not enough info... (ㅠ .ㅠ)